# C# - Adicionar MouseHover para cada Botão em um FlowLayout

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para adicionar um evento de MouseHover em cada botão existente em um FlowLayoutPanel?

Quero que quando passar o mouse em cada botão neste Panel o ponteiro do mouse mude para "Hand" e que a cor de fundo desse botão seja um azul mais claro

Código que tentei fazer:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Button bt in panelBotoes.Controls)
        {                
            bt.MouseHover += new EventHandler(focarBotao(bt));                
        }
    }

    private EventHandler focarBotao(Button bt)
    {
        bt.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
        return ?;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que primeiro percorrer os controles do `FlowLayoutPanel` mas apenas os do tipo `Button`, e depois associar o evento utilizando o `sender` do método:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Button b in panelBotoes.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        b.MouseHover += B_MouseHover;
    }
}

private void B_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    ((Button)sender).Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!